# Transparent Image Overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a partially transparent blue overlay on an image. Like this-
http://tinypic.com/r/2gtnq0i/9

Here is my attempt:
https://jsfiddle.net/ypqL4zL4/

I thought that setting

```
z-index: 10;
```

would solve the issue, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the image is contained within the element that has a background, so you can't see the background since the image is blocking it. Instead, have a `div` that contains the image, then the overlay. Here's the code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-size{
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.overlay{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(66, 134, 244,.7);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image-size" src="http://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/30-impossibly-cute-puppies/impossibly-cute-puppy-8.jpg">
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```